# eledmac: Is it possible to attach a footnote to a non-numbered paragraph?

Tags: eledmac

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{eledmac}

\footparagraph{A}               
\foottwocol{B} 
\let\variant=\Afootnote                 
\let\note=\Bfootnote 

\lineation{section}                 
\linenummargin{right}               

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering

\pstart \edtext{Here}{\note{This is a footnote on the word here.}} is some text 
that has a footnote attached to the word here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a ante euismod, iaculis elit nec, tincidunt 
tellus. Morbi nec nibh tortor. Integer gravida, neque vel molestie ullamcorper,
nisi velit consectetur mi, ac blandit dui neque ut libero. In nec sapien tellus
Ut mollis ante odio, ac tempor quam ultricies sed. Fusce enim sem, facilisis et
porttitor aliquam, porta vel est. Aenean ut risus a odio ornare ultrices.\pend

This is a \edtext{non-numbered}{\note{This is the footnote I wish I could add.}}
paragraph because it's not within pstart and pend. I want to be able to put a 
footnote on it. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a 
ante euismod, iaculis elit nec, tincidunt tellus. Morbi nec nibh tortor. Integer
gravida, neque vel molestie ullamcorper, nisi velit consectetur mi, ac blandit 
dui neque ut libero. In nec sapien tellus. Ut mollis ante odio, ac tempor 
quam ultricies sed. Fusce enim sem, facilisis et porttitor aliquam, porta vel 
est. Aenean ut risus a odio ornare ultrices. 

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: @cmc117: Your example does not compile.

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to achieve?  Why do you not wish to number the second paragraph?

Comment: I'm working on a play text. Some of the lines are numbered (those the characters speak) and some are not (stage directions, costuming notes and the like).

Comment: eledmac uses the line number for the note, rather than generating consecutive numbers as with a standard footnote. I think this is the reason I can't put a note on a non-numbered section--eledmac can't figure out what to put for the number of the note on a non-numbered line. I'd like to use symbols where I need to attach a note to a stage direction or other non-numbered section, so I'm wondering if there's a workaround that will allow me to do so.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I included code for the problem I'm having. It compiles if you remove the \edtext note in the second paragraph. I'm new here, so I'm sorry if that wasn't the right example to post.

Comment: @cmc117: I do not want to distract you or lead you off the path you are going, but have seen the `screenplay` package? Perhaps, it will work for your purposes too?

Comment: Sorry, what do want to have? a critical note without line numbering is a non sense. ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to over-think this.  Why not simply use:

```
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
```

--- and then a simple:

```
\footnote{This is a 'symbol' footnote outside of the 'pstart-pend' environments.}
```

..?  In other words, do something like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage{eledmac}                                     
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}

\footparagraph{A} 
\foottwocol{B} 
\let\variant=\Afootnote                        
\let\note=\Bfootnote 
\let\nnote=\footnote  % <-- added

\lineation{section} 
\linenummargin{right}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart 

\edtext{Here}{\note{This is a footnote on the word here.}} %
is some text that has a footnote attached to the word here. 
\pend  

% This is a \edtext{non-numbered}{\note{This is the footnote I wish I could add.}}
This is a non-numbered\nnote{This is the footnote I wish I could add.} %
paragraph because it's not within pstart and pend. I want to be able to put a footnote on it. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a
ante euismod, iaculis elit nec, tincidunt tellus. Morbi nec nibh tortor.  

% And we can start numbering again....
\pstart 
\edtext{Here}{\note{This is a footnote on the word here.}} is some text 
that has a footnote attached to the word here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
\pend

\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: Jon, thank you. Footmisc doesn't appear to support multiple footnote streams. Some non-numbered text needs an explanatory note (A stream) and some needs a textual variant note (B stream) or both, so I don't think it will quite resolve the problem.

eg. a stage direction is not a numbered line, and so it is outside the pstart/pend environment, but it might need an explanatory note of a term as well as textual variant notes to account for differences between the copy text and other manuscripts. Many editions mark with "SD" instead of a line number, but a symbol series would work perfectly.

Comment: @cmc117 -- Oh, *two* "non-critical" footnote streams?  Then maybe use `\footnoteA` and `\footnoteB` (from `eledmac`).  For the "stage direction" notes, you could also fiddle with the commands `\thefootnoteA`, `\bodyfootmarkA`, and `\footfootmarkA` (for the A-level); e.g., try `\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{SD-\arabic{footnoteA}}`.